# Logging a PostgreSQL session in text file

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to log a complete session in psql into a .txt file. The command given to me was initially this:

```
psql db_name| tee file_name.txt
```

However, my SSH client does nothing until I quit it. That means, it does not recognize any command. More like a document, no action happens no matter what I write. So far, only `'\q'` is recognised which lets me get out of it. Any ideas what is happening? How am I to write the query if shell will not read anything. Also, I tried the following (this is before connecting to database) :

```
script filename.txt
```

It does show the message : `script started, file is filename.txt`, but I dont know where this file is stored and how to retrieve it.

Any help with the above will be welcome and really appreciated! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You choose where script should store the file by giving the file as the first argument! If invoked as you have shown, the file will be in the directory you started the command.

Comment: ok. so can I store the file on my local PC as well? Do I have to give the file-address for the same? Also, which command do you refer to for 'giving the file as the first argument' ? Thanks :)

Comment: The file will be saved on the machine on which you run the "script filename.txt" command on. That is the command I refer to. Note that when you are done with your session, you should type "exit" to have the file written. script will then display "Script done, file is filename.txt". Please look at the manual for script(1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is option to psql for log query and results:

> **-L filename**
> --log-file filename
>
> Write all query output into file ***filename***, in addition to the normal output destination.

Try this:

```
psql db_name -L file_name.txt
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. No however, I need to send both commands and results to a text file, in addition to them being displayed on the screen. I have located the textfile being created with 'script' command, but it is empty, even though I have output on the screen. Any ideas?